# sorting vector of pair of vectors

Tags: c++

I have data in the following form:

```
vector<pair<unsigned, pair<vector<unsigned>, vector<unsigned> > > > A;

5,((0,9),(1,2))
6, ((0),(8,9))
10,((1,10,15,16),(1,2))
2,((0,2,10),(8,9))
3,((0,1,2),(1,2))
1,((3,4,7),(1,2))
7,((3,4,6),(8,9))
11,((1,51,9,3,2,4,6),(8,9))
```

Such that the sorted output appears as:

```
3,((0,1,2),(1,2))
5,((0,9),(1,2))
1,((3,4,7),(1,2))
10,((1,10,15,16),(1,2))
6, ((0),(8,9))
7,((3,4,6),(8,9))
2,((0,2,10),(8,9))
11,((1,51,9,3,2,4,6),(8,9))
```

That is I want to sort by the second pair of the vector A. Such that I group together the elements by the second pair of vector of second pair of vector A. E.g, here I group together all elements containing (1,2) and (8,9). Then I want to sort the first pair of vector of second pair of vector A according to the following (start,end) ranges. That is, the elements whose vectors lie between (0,0) appear before elements whose vectors lie between (0,1). E.g. in the example (0,1,2) appears before (0,9) as its elements lie between (0,2) which appears before (0,9) in the said order...similarly for the other elements:

```
(Start,End)
(0,0),
(0,1),
(1,1),
(0,2),
(1,2),
(2,2),
(0,3),
(1,3),
(2,3),
(3,3),
(0,4),
(1,4),
(2,4),
(3,4),
(4,4),
(0,5),
(1,5),
(2,5),
(3,5),
(4,5),
(5,5),
(0,6),
(1,6),
(2,6),
(3,6),
(4,6),
(5,6),
(6,6),
(0,7),
(1,7),
(2,7),
(3,7),
(4,7),
(5,7),
(6,7),
(7,7),
(0,8),
(1,8),
(2,8),
(3,8),
(4,8),
(5,8),
(6,8),
(7,8),
(8,8),
.
.
(n,n)
```

I am running C++ using g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3.

I tried to solve this problem by: first I group together the elements like (1,2) and (8,9). Then I store these ranges in another data structure. Then I iterate over these ranges and try to see if a row falls in the said range or not

Comment: Indeed problems such as these arise tautologically: obtuse data structures always lead to mayhem.

Comment: Did you try to write a program to solve this?

Comment: @Matt Yes I did. It is brute force approach where in another data structure first I group together the elements like (1,2) and (8,9). Then I store these ranges in another data structure. Then I iterate over these ranges and try to see if a row falls in the said range or not.

Comment: @Bathsheba Is it a problem because of the data structure. Can you please suggest some other data structure which I can use. I'll be really thankful to you for the same

Comment: You could use a vector<vector<unsigned> > and the std::sort

Comment: @StegVerner Maybe telling us what these structures represent and what your goal in sorting them would help us suggest an alternate?

Comment: @JonathanMee The first element of vector A here is a key element. The first vector second pair represents some ranges in which the key can lie e.g. (0 to 9), etc. And the second vector of second pair represent their labels, which I have assigned as integers. Thanks a lot for your comment

Comment: why do you use such a strange type ? It is too confusing.. "I want to sort by the second pair of the vector A"... you vector has only one pair (that is made up by an unsigned and another pair). Somehow it sounds like you dont know yourself, why you are using such obscure type ;)

Comment: @StegVerner So `unsigned` is a key... to what? The first `vector` is a range... but contains more than 2 elements, what is a range with 3 elements? The second `vector` represents "their labels"... is they the first `vecto`r, why does a range need labels? I need more clarification about what all this means, I think the right proposition here is to clean up your data structure, but I can't even understand what it does here.

Comment: @JonathanMee The first unsigned is a key identifying the second pair. Here, range like (0,3,9) means the key can assume values 0,3,9 and the labels stand for iris_images which I have given numerical value :)

Comment: @StegVerner OK, I'm understanding a bit more. Why do you need a key to the second pair, could you not just iterate over the them? Also, can you explain why you need a `vector` to represent the "iris_images"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have a particularly complicated data structure with a super specific and arbitrarily ordering that you want to define on it, but no matter. The nice thing about [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) is that it's completely accommodating:

```
std::sort(A.begin(), A.end(), MyComparator);
```

All you need to write is:

```
typedef pair<unsigned, pair<vector<unsigned>, vector<unsigned> > > Elem;

bool MyComparator(const Elem& a, const Elem& b) {
    // return true if a should go before b in the sort

    // step 1 is apparently to do a vector comparison
    for (size_t i = 0; i < a.second.second.size(); ++i) {
        if (i == b.second.second.size()) {
            return false;           
        }
        else if (a[i] < b[i]) {
            return true;
        }
        else if (a[i] > b[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (a.second.second.size() < b.second.second.size()) {
        return true;
    }

    // if we got here, the two vectors compare equal
    // so onto the next steps 2, 3, ...
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. But I do not know why it is giving me the wrong output: https://ideone.com/M5dpY2

Comment: @StegVerner By "etc." I mean "fill in your own additional logic here". As is, the function exhibits undefined behavior if the vectors are equal...

Comment: Oh sorry but I am still not able to  understand. I do not have any additional logic here.

Comment: @StegVerner "Then I want to sort the first pair of vector of second pair of vector A according to the following (start,end) ranges." ?

Comment: @StegVerner Note that this will not sort as you desire, cause the `if (a.second.second.size() < b.second.second.size())` will indicate that a range of (0, 1, 2) is greater than a range of (0, 4).